# Ways to speed up javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator?

Tags: java, json, performance, serialization

I'm finally refactoring a restful web service, which yields json output to use an actual json lib, vs manually constructing the json into a StringBuilder and then printing that to the output.
Speed is crucial, and currently I'm seeing very poor performance with subject.
I have a small benchmark test, where 4 threads are collectively performing ~ 4k requests, and this takes ~5,5s with StringBuilder, and 134s with JsonGenerator.
I'm hoping that I've done something wrong.
I'm following this guide: http://www.journaldev.com/2315/java-json-example.

Should I rather be looking into other libs for speed? I really prefer using oracle libs, as they are already present on my app server (glass fish)

UPDATE

It was indeed a mistake - but I did go through the motions of implementing my very own JsonGenerator, which seems to perform a whole lot better than any of the alternatives:

- StringBuilder took: 4319 ms
- FastJsonGenerator took: 1969 ms (my baby)
- JsonGenerator took: 3550 ms  (Json.createJsonGenerator)
- JsonObject took: 84829 ms (javax.json.JsonObjectBuilder)

I put the code onto GitHub: https://github.com/steffenschumacher/FastJsonGenerator
My laziness kept me from writing a proper test, and it ended up costing me more time than it needed to. My original test were flawed:

- dependant on database connections to get real data
- spent CPU time on parsing the json answer
- spent CPU time on actually passing the response over local http.

The GitHub code writes the output into /dev/null and doesn't parse, and doesn't use dynamic data, but rather uses data instantiated in advance.
Thanks for all the pointers - I think I have what i need now.

Comment: Any only-java lib for json will be slower than good StringBuilder approach.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki But factor 20 is suspicious.

Comment: I'd try profiling it first, the difference in time is suspicious. I'd expect a slowdown with JSON library vs. StringBuilder but not so drastic. There might be something wrong with your code.

Comment: ok, the factor of 20 for javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator is little suspicious, show your code,

Comment: Code is a bit extensive, but if I don't figure out the issue, I'll build example code to post..

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Yeah - explained in the update of the main problem - dumb bug caused the load on StringBuilder to be 1/40 of JsonGenerator. But I did learn how to build a more efficient impl than oracle at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator, it seems, that it should be almost as fast as StringBuilder (but with proper and maybe optimised implementation).
But javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator is an interface, what underlying implementation do you use, is it jsonp?

All json libraries for java use some kind of internal structure, like maps, lists, arrays and/or reflection to be able to deal with the nature of json string - which almost doesn't have any restriction to its structure - this makes it so powerfull to transfer data, but also implies that the json-dealing libraries needs to be very generic in their nature, if something is very genereic then usually it is slow, because it is hard to optimise it for the "unknown". To construct a json string from such data is slower than just adding strings together, that's why StringBuilder approach is so fast.

There is no java-only json lib, that could be faster than good StringBuilder approach.

you could make the StringBuilder-like approach even faster using byte[] arrays with prepared data to send  (like elements of the json message structure) instead of Strings with StringBuilder. So basically you could send parts of json message directly from the arrays of `bytes[]` containing constant prepared parts of the message, and put data in beetween.

Comment: Curious - the JsonGenerator API could be implemented so that it supports the StringBuilder 'way' I would think, since you have to add all nodes in proper order/ maintain hierarchy depts manually anyways. It would need some internal state (pos {root, inObj, inArr}, depth to ensure we end in root, and possibly some buffer (bytes[]) for efficient writing to the outputStream, but if this is the case, then why isn't this how it works? I must be missing something..

Comment: Not adding the chunks of data to the output is expensive, but traversing thru the structure of data to collect things that should be added is expensive - be it using reflection, or using some kind of collections. Using straight StringBuilder approach, you usually don't need to travel thru any data structure, you just access and add data directly, which always will be faster that using library with generic data structure.

Comment: But I fail to see why JsonGenerator needs to add any of its data to any structure, but rather serialise it as data is fed to it, unlike the non-streaming variant, which I completely get has overhead..